# Using php to fax html

Tags: php, mysql, html, fax

I used to select data from mysql database by joining tables using PHP and output any html I wish to have. Recently, I wish to send out the html to my client via fax, and I found it is not as easy as sending emails.

I have thought of a number of ways.

1. to screen print the content as an image, and fax out the image;
2. to output the page into a word document, and fax out the file;
3. to package the content (not in html format, that is, text only) and write it into a database and fax out the data;
4. to fax out the html page directly.

Actually, what will be people's practice in doing similar tasks? And by what way that is common to achieve it?

Thank you.

Comment: Which part of the process are you having trouble with, turning the HTML file into an image or the faxing part? Both are not entirely trivial. What kind of a platform is this all running on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do is convert the HTML code to a pdf-document and then fax it.

dompdf does exactly that for PHP:

http://code.google.com/p/dompdf/